# why android studio 1 shows no suggestion for button in initialization

Tags: android

I am  trying this using  new android studio 1 from past 3 days, but ) can't solve the above problem:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

edittext

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: what is the `edittext` here.?

Comment: You should probably tell us what the problem is and what you're trying to do.

Comment: This isn't a question anyone can help with, there is no explanation as to what you are trying to do, nor what the problem is and there seems to be a random edittext floating in the middle for some reason

Answer (score 0):

If you were able to see the suggestion but not now, then there is a possible case (always happens with me):

**In most IDE you will not see suggestion in the current line, if you have any error** (mostly compilation) **in the previous lines**